# Django URL Dispatcher

Tags: django, url, dispatcher

I have been working on a new Django site and I am having problems with the url dispatcher.

Basically I need help getting the following urls working.

```
/site/aaa-00

/site/aaa-00-00
```

I have looked at the URL dispatcher on django docs and im more confused now.

```
url(r'^/site/(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$', 'rollout.views.update'),
```

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems? What have you tried?

Comment: Any code written so far? This is not specific enough to help.

Comment: sorry, added some code i already have

Answer (score 2):

Your regex isn't going to do the job. I'd expect it to look more like:

```
^site/(?P<path>[-\w]+)/$
```

to do what you want. Two main differences: *URL patterns shouldn't match against a leading slash*, ie the slash gets stripped (or, more accurately, isn't part of the path component of a URL, but that's getting pedantic); and `?P` in expressions should take a name for the group (which gets converted into a parameter to your view function).

One other thing you may not be aware of: you have a trailing `/` at the end of your URLconf line, but not in the URLs you're trying to match. Note that by default Django (with the `CommonMiddleware` running) will auto-redirect to include a trailing `/` unless the path already matches something in the URLconf; this can be controlled using [the `APPEND_SLASH` configuration option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash). That should "just work" in your case, although it results in a redirect so you shouldn't emit URLs without the trailing slash (or make the slash optional in the URLconf).